Fluid: Sort records by date using ViewHelper iterator.sort
I have a list of records; all of them have a field .datetime (of type DateTime)
As step one, I want to have a loop for all records in ascending date order. Step two will be a "sort by pid", followed by a third step "sort by time".
But I can't get the VHS ViewHelper to work...
<f:for each="{recordlist -> v:iterator.sort(sortBy: '{f:format.date(date:recordlist.datetime, format:'Ymd')}')}" as="sortedrecord"> // iterating data which is ONLY sorted while rendering this particular loop {sortrecord.datetime}<br /> </f:for>
ends up in
#1256475113 InvalidArgumentException The argument "each" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper "TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\ViewHelpers\ForViewHelper".
Any idea how to make the iterator.sort work with a formatted date?
((Iterating directly over the dtaetime field will not work (iterator expects a string type variable), + cant get other inline format options to work.))

Sorting by three arguments/columns sounds more like a job for your repository/dataprocessor than for the templating... What speaks against sorting directly when reading from the database?

First: I can't make the third party extension to support that kind of sorting
Second: I prefer to have as less as possible additional code that might break some update.
But it looks as if there is no other way to go.

You will need to sort the array before formatting the date.
<f:for each="{recordlist -> v:iterator.sort(sortBy: 'datetime')}" as="record">
    {record -> f:format.date(format: 'Ymd')}
</f:for>

It's not possible to sort formatted dates properly.

OK, sounds as if I need to write my own ViewHelper - iterator.sort doesn't work with DateTime objects (needs string instead).
And just sorting by the datetime field doenst help, b/c I need the first level of grouping on granularity of a single day; iterating by datetime makes a group for 202406241000, one for 202406241030 and one for 202406241600...
